# How to see sikuli logs during execution?

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I'm trying to output some debug info in a Sikuli script using `print` but I can see this info only after the script has finished execution because the IDE hides itself while the script is running. Is there a way to see those logs during execution? Like outputting this info to console or (better) not hiding IDE during execution?

Answer (score 2):

(1) You could use a pop-up:

```
popup("Hello World")
```

(2) You can use Jython's File IO

```
f = open("myLogfile.txt", 'a')
f.write("Log Message")
f.close()
```

Now if you open the log file in a text editor that warns about changes made to the file (ie NOT Notepad.exe), you can then see your print statements every time the file is appended by your script.

Comment: I get permission denied when I try method 2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the IDE in background during script execution.
However,there's an alternative to view the logs.

You can install the package which launches your sikuli via command prompt(sikuli-script.jar),
refer to https://launchpad.net/raiman/+download

you won't need the IDE to launch your scripts this way.

Now after changing necessary environment settings you can type-in simple path like "java -jar %Sikuli_Home%\sikuli-script.jar -r %Sikuli_Scripts%\main.sikuli" in cmd and get started.

here 'main' is my driver script where I have imported my modules under single .sikuli folder (main.sikuli) you can have any file name like abc.sikuli

(here you need to store your path in a variable like ,path = os.environ['Sikuli_Scripts'])

Also ,it is a good practice to launch applications creating batch files and accessing files using relative path.